# Is there a way to call dispatch "statically" outside a connected component with react-redux?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, firebase-authentication, react-redux

Consider the following code:

```
/**
 * OTHER IMPORTS...
 */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose} from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';

/**
 * Connected Router - Flux Router with Connected Redux
 */
const ReduxRouter = connect()(Router);

class MyApp extends Component {

    // Many Methods

    /**
     *
     */
    componentWillMount () {

        firebase.initializeApp({});

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChangedCallback.bind(this));

        if (!this.reducers) {

            this.reducers = combineReducers({
                ... // Many Reducers for other Scenes
            });

        }

        if (!this.store) {

            this.store = compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))(createStore)(this.reducers);

        }

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    onAuthStateChangedCallback (user) {

        if (user) {

            /*

            // TODO DISPATCH <------ Here is my problem

            dispatch({
                type: 'LOGGED',
                payload: user
            });

            */

            Actions.First();

        } else {

            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                loggedIn: false
            });

            Actions.LogIn();

        }

    }

    render () {

        return (
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <ReduxRouter sceneStyle={{paddingTop: 0, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}>
                    <Scene key="Menu" component={MenuScene} open={false} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} passProps>
                        {/* MANY OTHERS SCENES */}
                        <Scene key="First" title="First" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} component={FirstScene} passProps />
                        <Scene key="LogIn" title="LogIn" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} component={LogInScene} passProps />
                    </Scene>
                </ReduxRouter>
            </Provider>
        );

    }

}

export default MyApp
```

All my scenes inside "Menu", including it are connected components

```
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        ...state.First
    };

};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
   ... // Actions
})(First);
```

I decided to set firebase auth callback here, in the main component. There is a scenario where I need to dispatch some action so all my scenes read the data that should be dispatched in this case.

So, here is the question: is there a way to call dispatch outside a connect component or is a bet way to connect the "MyApp" component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things.

First, ideally you should be creating the store *outside* the component hierarchy, usually in your applications entry point.  For example:

```
// index.js

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Second, you can either pass `dispatch` down as a prop through the component hierarchy, or just connect additional components.  Basically, any component that wants to interact with the store should use `connect()`.  If you do not pass in a `mapDispatchToProps` function into `connect`, your component will automatically be given `props.dispatch`.

Comment: Hey markerikson... due to the limit of the comment, I post my considerations answering my quesiton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Great approach! Along with your suggestion, I checked out the [docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md#about-key-xxx-is-already-defined) and finally got this structure for my `index.js`. I think the code explains the structure by itself. Thanks again for your help!

```
/**
* Modules dependencies
*/
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState} from 'react-native';
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose} from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Scene, Router, ActionConst, Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import firebase from 'firebase';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import {default as MyScene1Reducer} from './MyScene1/reducer';
import {default as MyScene2Reducer} from './MyScene2/reducer';
import {default as MyScene3Reducer} from './MyScene3/reducer';

import {default as MyScene1} from './MyScene1';
import {default as MyScene2} from './MyScene2';
import {default as MyScene3} from './MyScene3';

/**
 * Firebase
 */
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: ''
});

/**
 * Scenes
 */
const Scenes = Actions.create(
    <Scene key="Menu" component={MenuScene} open={false} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} passProps>
        <Scene key="MyScene1" title="MyScene1" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} component={MyScene1} passProps />
        <Scene key="MyScene2" title="MyScene2" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} component={MyScene2} passProps />
        <Scene key="MyScene3" title="MyScene3" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} component={MyScene3} passProps />
    </Scene>
 );

const ReduxRouter = connect()(Router);

const Reducers = combineReducers({
    MyScene1: MyScene1Reducer,
    MyScene2: MyScene2Reducer,
    MyScene3: MyScene3Reducer
});

const Store = compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))(createStore)(Reducers);

/**
 * The Main Component - View
 */
class MyApp extends Component {

    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {

        };

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    componentWillMount () {

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChangedCallback.bind(this));

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    componentDidMount () {

        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChangeCallback);

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    componentWillUnmount() {

        AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChangeCallback);

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    onAppStateChangeCallback = (nextAppState) => {

        console.log(nextAppState);

    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    onAuthStateChangedCallback (user) {

        if (user) {

            console.log(this.props.dispatch); <---- Exists!

            Actions.MyScene2();

        } else {

            Actions.MyScene3();

        }

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    render () {

        return (
            <ReduxRouter scenes={Scenes} sceneStyle={{paddingTop: 0, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}} />
        );

    }

}

/**
* The Main Component - Provider / Store
*/
const MyAppStore = () => {

    const MyAppConnected = connect()(MyApp);

    return (
        <Provider store={Store}>
            <MyAppConnected />
        </Provider>
    );

};

export default MyAppStore;
```